# VB.NET Disallowing user to leave form until closed

Tags: windows, winforms, vb.net-2010

I'm trying to imitate a feature of Windows. For example, when you're in a folder's properties, and then open the 'Advanced' popup from the properties page; if you try to click out of it the menubar flashes and a windows error sound is made. It is not until you close the popup by pressing okay or cancel or X that you can continue.

I would like to imitate this feature in my VB.NET project, thinking there would be an easy enough way to do this, but I cannot find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show the second form as [Dialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx) from the first form. While the second form is still open, user can't interact with the first form.